# Randomise Table data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Our client has asked us to randomise some contact data before we export data from a live database.

My plan was to create a copy of the contact table, and then update the copied tables "FIRST_NAME" using a random row from the original table, and then update the "LAST_NAME" using a different random row of the original table.

Any idea how to do this? FYI, it's an oracle 10 db and I'm using SQL developer to do the work.

Comment: Well I did consider creating a table of random names and this is also fine. We don't want to pay for a tool. Anonymising the data from a table of fake data is fine.

Comment: Can you actually help with the SQL rather than commenting on unrelated things like GDPR? You have no information as to my client, or what data is stored or what processing is being done on the data, so speculating on GDPR and how this may affect the data is pointless.

Comment: I've imported a table of random FIRST, LAST & COMPANY names and I currently have the following code:`Update CONTACT_EX2 SET FIRST_NAME = ( SELECT FIRST FROM ( SELECT FIRST FROM ANONYMISED_NAMES ORDER BY dbms_random.value ) WHERE rownum = 1);` however this sets all First names to the same value. How do I set a different value for each row of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose a hash function: [STANDARD_HASH](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647)

By this the data gets anonymized but the customer is still able to use the data and run joins, analytic, etc.

```
SELECT 
    RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('Wernfried', 'SHA1')) AS SHA1,
    RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('Wernfried', 'SHA256')) AS SHA256,
    RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('Wernfried', 'SHA384')) AS SHA384,
    RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('Wernfried', 'SHA512')) AS SHA512,
    RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('Wernfried', 'MD5')) AS MD5
FROM dual;
```

So, something like

```
UPDATE my_table SET 
    FIRST_NAME = RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('secretPrefix'||FIRST_NAME, 'MD5')),
    LAST_NAME = RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH('secretPrefix'||LAST_NAME, 'MD5'));
```

Where "my_table" is of course a copy of your original data. I set a `'secretPrefix'` because otherwise it would be rather simple to revert the hash value just by reading and hashing all names from a telephone directory for example.

**Update**

```
ALTER TABLE CONTACTS ADD (rn  NUMBER);
UPDATE CONTACTS a SET rn = (SELECT RN FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) AS RN, ROWID AS ROW_ID FROM CONTACTS b) WHERE a.rowid = ROW_ID);

UPDATE CONTACTS a SET (first_name, last_Name) = (
SELECT first_name, last_Name 
FROM (SELECT first_name, last_Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) AS RN FROM ANONYMISED_NAMES) r WHERE r.RN = a.RN)
```

Note, for this update the amount of random names must be equal or bigger than table of real names. Otherwise you may use `MOD` function.

Comment: I've imported a table of random FIRST, LAST & COMPANY names and I currently have the following code:`Update CONTACT_EX2 
SET FIRST_NAME = (
SELECT FIRST FROM
( SELECT FIRST FROM ANONYMISED_NAMES
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1);` however this sets all First names to the same value. How do I select a different value for each row of the table?

Comment: Why not simply `UPDATE my_table SET FIRST = dbms_random.value;`?

Comment: That just generates a random string of numbers. Isn't going to look very good in the UI after we've imported the data into the test system.

Comment: It depends what do you want. Just mixing up the names, replace by random (but real) names, random strings, etc. Please specify.

Comment: I want to replace the existing names with real random names, either by reusing the names from the original table, or by using a table of random names.

Comment: in update, You get the associated names from one entry and assign the other one. But names should not be related ...

Comment: You're update looks good - rather than setting a random number calculated on the total number of rows, can you set it simply to a value between 1 & 50?

Comment: Actually sorted it using `UPDATE CONTACT_EX2 a SET rn = TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,51));`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE CONTACT_EX2 ADD (rn NUMBER);
UPDATE CONTACT_EX2 a SET rn = TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,101));

UPDATE CONTACT_EX2 SET (FIRST_NAME) = (
SELECT FIRST
FROM (SELECT * FROM ANONYMISED_NAMES) WHERE ROW_NUM = CONTACT_EX2.RN);`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into NewTable(...., name, last_name)
select ...., n.name, l.last_name
  from OldTable u,
       (select count(distinct name) name_count, count(distinct last_name) last_name_count
          from OldTable) c,
       (select name, row_number() over(order by DBMS_RANDOM.value) as id
          from (select distinct name from OldTable)
       ) n,
       (select last_name, row_number() over(order by DBMS_RANDOM.value) as id
          from (select distinct last_name from OldTable)
       ) l
 where n.id=mod(u.ID, c.name_count)+1 and l.id=mod(u.ID, c.last_name_count)+1
```

`u.ID` - is primary key of source table or other unique, "random" integer value.

Comment: I don't want to create a new table, I want to do an update on a copy of the existing table as there is other data that we want to keep and not  be anonymised.

Comment: @TomBridges how do you create a copy of the table, is not it using INSERT 
 or "Create table AS select" ?

Comment: @TomBridges You do not need a table at all, you can create VIEW with the above query. Or update copy table with data from this view.

Comment: I created the copy of the table first, just by r-clicking -> Table -> Copy. So I want to UPDATE the copied table.

Comment: @TomBridges Create a table copy with SQL-query, simultaneously with changing the names. Or use this query in the UPDATE or MERGE clause. In any case, it only shows the direction, you will have to adapt the query to your structure.

Comment: What is the SQL code to do the simultaneous name change? I know how to create a table copy `CREATE TABLE CONTACT_EX2 AS SELECT * FROM CONTACT_EX;` but not sure how you change the data at the same time

Comment: @TomBridges `create table as <select_from_this_answer>`, change `....` in query to column list, except name and last_name

Comment: `CREATE TABLE CONTACT_EX2 
AS 
SELECT a.ID, b.FIRST_NAME
FROM  (SELECT ID from CONTACT_EX) a,
      (SELECT FIRST_NAME from ( SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM ANONYMISED_NAMES ORDER BY dbms_random.value )) b;` This results in all the Names being the same

Comment: @TomBridges Of course, you will only get one name. My query get all possible names are obtained and one of them is selected separately for each record.

Comment: @TomBridges I get "rownum" - sequence number of name in list and join it to data record on the remainder of dividing data ID by the number of names

Comment: @TomBridges For reliability "rownum" can be replaced with "row_number() over(order by DBMS_RANDOM.value)"